# How to Create Migration on Runtime in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-3.0

Is there any possible way to create migration on runtime in efcore.

```
context.Database.Migrate();
```

Before this code, I need a code that, when I started my app, should create a migration about diff between postgresql database tables and ef models.

Is there any way to do this?

```
PM> enable-migrations
PM> add-migration initial
PM> update-database
```

I dont want to use these ones. I want to make these code's jobs on runtime. I hope I could explain myself clearly.

Comment: I haven't done it myself, but it seems it's possible through the EF Core APIs. For example this [IMigrationsModelDiffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.imigrationsmodeldiffer?view=efcore-3.1) interface lets you compare two models and generate an migration if they differ,

Answer (score 1):

Note, you need to re-compile the app after calling Add-Migration. It's very difficult to do this while the app is running.

Have a read through the closed [Automatic Migrations](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/6214#issuecomment-332980580) issue for some alternative solutions.